# Is it possible for me to deploy an azure web app by zip on Visual studio Team service?

Tags: node.js, azure, angular5, azure-pipelines, azure-web-app-service

I built a azure web app which link to my work account. Now I want to use my personal account to put it on Visual Studio TEAM Service(for continuous dev). I know I need to create a build for it....but since my personal account doesn't link to the web app, I can't use the azure web app template. After searching online, I found a way to do it, which is by a publish.js. Since it is working for azure bot service, so I just give a try. However, after the build is completed, I noticed the change does not gets reflect on the web app....I wonder Is it possible for me to deploy an azure web app by zip on Visual studio Team service?

Here sample publish.js code:

```
var zipFolder = require('zip-folder');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');

var rootFolder = path.resolve('.');
var zipPath = path.resolve(rootFolder, './test.zip');
var kuduApi = '';
var userName = '';
var password = '';

function uploadZip(callback) {
  fs.createReadStream(zipPath).pipe(request.put(kuduApi, {
    auth: { 
      username: userName,
      password: password,
      sendImmediately: true
    },
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "applicaton/zip"
    }
  }))
  .on('response', function(resp){
    if (resp.statusCode >= 200 && resp.statusCode < 300) {
      fs.unlink(zipPath);
      callback(null);
    } else if (resp.statusCode >= 400) {
      callback(resp);
    }
  })
  .on('error', function(err) {
    callback(err)
  });
}

function publish(callback) {
  zipFolder(rootFolder, zipPath, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
      uploadZip(callback);
    } else {
      callback(err);
    }
  })
}

publish(function(err) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log('testit-89d8 publish');
  } else {
    console.error('failed to publish testit-89d8', err);
  }
});
```

I found the error log, it is too long, so here it just a head of it:

failed to publish qnalist IncomingMessage {

```
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1013703Z   _readableState: 
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1013848Z    ReadableState {
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1013952Z      objectMode: false,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1014061Z      highWaterMark: 16384,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1014184Z      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1014367Z      length: 0,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1014485Z      pipes: null,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1014589Z      pipesCount: 0,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1014694Z      flowing: null,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1015019Z      ended: false,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1015112Z      endEmitted: false,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1015203Z      reading: false,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1015292Z      sync: true,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1015427Z      needReadable: false,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1015524Z      emittedReadable: false,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1015681Z      readableListening: false,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1015821Z      resumeScheduled: false,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1015928Z      destroyed: false,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1016022Z      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1016113Z      awaitDrain: 0,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1016253Z      readingMore: true,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1016343Z      decoder: null,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1016433Z      encoding: null },
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1016522Z   readable: true,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1016653Z   domain: null,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1016739Z   _events: 
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1016841Z    { end: [ [Function: responseOnEnd], [Function], [Object] ],
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1016980Z      close: [Function] },
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1017072Z   _eventsCount: 2,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1017164Z   _maxListeners: undefined,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1017252Z   socket: 
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1017377Z    TLSSocket {
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1017467Z      _tlsOptions: 
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1017557Z       { pipe: false,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1018481Z         secureContext: [Object],
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1018628Z         isServer: false,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1019590Z         requestCert: true,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1019690Z         rejectUnauthorized: true,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1019839Z         session: undefined,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1019937Z         NPNProtocols: undefined,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1020036Z         ALPNProtocols: undefined,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1020134Z         requestOCSP: undefined },
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1020267Z      _secureEstablished: true,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1020363Z      _securePending: false,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1020459Z      _newSessionPending: false,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1020555Z      _controlReleased: true,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1020690Z      _SNICallback: null,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1020783Z      servername: null,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1020877Z      npnProtocol: undefined,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1021011Z      alpnProtocol: false,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1021224Z      authorized: true,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1021637Z      authorizationError: null,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1021749Z      encrypted: true,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1021910Z      _events: 
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1022014Z       { close: [Array],
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1022119Z         end: [Array],
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1022232Z         finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1022399Z         _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1022514Z         secure: [Function],
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1022626Z         free: [Function: onFree],
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1022784Z         agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1022901Z         drain: [Function: ondrain],
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1023018Z         error: [Function: socketErrorListener],
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1023137Z         data: [Function: socketOnData] },
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1023285Z      _eventsCount: 10,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1023392Z      connecting: false,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1023497Z      _hadError: false,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1023598Z      _handle: 
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1023750Z       TLSWrap {
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1023856Z         _parent: [Object],
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1023965Z         _parentWrap: undefined,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1024126Z         _secureContext: [Object],
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1024235Z         reading: true,
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1024340Z         owner: [Circular],
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1024451Z         onread: [Function: onread],
2018-04-18T19:36:20.1024720Z         writeQueueSize: 0,
```

Comment: Add update and readable error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use zip deployment Kudu API (/api/zipdeploy).

[Deploying from a zip file](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-from-a-zip-file)

On the other hand, for Azure Web App deployment task, it uses the Azure subscription endpoint for authorization (Choose in Azure subscription input box of Azure App Service Deploy task).

Comment: For some personal reason, I don't want to use the azure web app deployment task, since my personal account is not relate to my work account. So I can't chose the web app from my subscription.

Comment: I guess the best way is to just using my working account. Any way, thanks for answering.